# Error with re.sub (re module python3) while replacing text that are inside parethesis/square bracket

Tags: python, regex, str-replace

I am not interested in replacing anything other than **[Krzyżowa pałac]** with **{{pl|[Krzyżowa pałac]}}**, But I am facing issues because the text is enclosed within [] . It also causes errors if the text is enclosed withing parenthesis.

```
import re

text = """Hello stack community ! I just wanna replace the following line
[Krzyżowa pałac]
but there's an error if it's enclosed within parenthesis/ square bracket
Can you please help me ! PLZ
}}"""

pagetext = text

regex = r"(\[(?:.*?)\])"
matches = re.finditer(regex, text, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        Desctext = match.group(1)


Desctext = Desctext.rstrip()
lang = "pl"
new_text = "{{" + lang + "|" + Desctext + "}}"


HereIsAnError = re.sub(Desctext, new_text, pagetext, 1)

print(HereIsAnError)
```

I am getting

```
Hell{{pl|[Krzyżowa pałac]}} stack community ! I just wanna replace the following line
[Krzyżowa pałac]
but there's an error if it's enclosed within parenthesis / square bracket
Can you please help me !
```

But I neee the following output

```
Hello stack community ! I just wanna replace the following line
{{pl|[Krzyżowa pałac]}}
but there's an error if it's enclosed within parenthesis / square bracket
Can you please help me !
```

Try this at https://repl.it/repls/HarmoniousMadeupBases

Comment: pl is polish language

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't just using the re.sub with the captured text like: https://repl.it/repls/ImportantLimegreenNumerators

Answer (score 0):

Use replace instead of re.sub

```
import re

text = """Hello stack community ! I just wanna replace the following line
[Krzyżowa pałac]
but there's an error if it's enclosed within parenthesis/ square bracket
Can you please help me ! PLZ
}}"""

pagetext = text

regex = r"(\[(?:.*?)\])"
matches = re.finditer(regex, text, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        Desctext = match.group(1)


Desctext = Desctext.rstrip()
lang = "pl"
new_text = "{{" + lang + "|" + Desctext + "}}"

HereWasAnError = pagetext.replace(Desctext, new_text, 1)

print(HereWasAnError)
```

Comment: `(?:.*?)` = `.*?`

Comment: Is this an answer or an addendum to the question?